# matplotlib chart label format millions short

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a pie chart that includes long numbers and things overlab. I was wondering if there is a way to change the label format for millions to do $1M instead of $1,000,000. Below is my code and I also attached a snapshot of the issue:

```
ax0.pie(stats_df['sum'], labels=stats_df['type'], 
        autopct=lambda p: '{:.2f}%(${:,.0f})'.format(p, 
       (p/100)*stats_df['sum'].sum()), textprops={'fontsize': 10})
```

[image: matplotlib pie chart]

Comment: Divide your number by 1000000 ?

Comment: that turn 1000000 to 100. I think I need to move the comma.

Comment: Not sure what you want. $ 100000000 divided by 1000000 are $ 100 M, which as I understand it, is what you want.

Comment: Sorry I meant to type 1,000,000. Thin the problem is in here: (${:,.0f})